# How to know how many pixels needed to vertically center with absolute positioning?

Tags: html, css

I was looking at the slideshow example from [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_slideshow_multiple):

My question only has to do with the `margin-top: -22px;` in the `.prev` and `.next` styles (line 31). How did they know to choose that number to exactly center the buttons vertically? For example, how did they know not to do something like `-20px` or `-25px` etc.

Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wo73jn8z/

Comment: I actually think that the correct value to have it perfectly centered would be `margin-top: -27px`, this being the result of `-((22px + 16px + 16px) / 2)`, where `22px` is the size of the `<` image, and `16px` the top and bottom padding.

Comment: Instead of margin-top: -22px;  we can use transform: translate(-50%) for proper vertical center. margin may vary depending on screen sizes. so better to user transform property. http://jsfiddle.net/wo73jn8z/1/

Comment: You can also use css display: flex; align-items: center; - in order to center vertically

Comment: @MartinZeltin additionally you can use `justify-content: center;` to center it horizontally.

Comment: Thanks all for your comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to know how many pixels to set vertically center because you can set automatically by use the percentage value.

remove `margin-top: -22px;`

and then add `transform: translateY(-50%); //it is use with top: 50%;`

I have try in your JSFiddle and it work fine.

*Remark:
You can edit % if it's not center, in this case I use -40% it will display like example from W3Schools.*

here is the source of answer:
https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Answer (score 2):

```
margin:0;
top:50%;
transform:translateY(-50%);
```

enter this properties will centralize your buttons no need to calculate pixels it will automatically calculate it